# What is global `this` in `node.js`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've googled around and it seems that `global` object could be treated as global object (similar to `window` in a browser, but not an equivalent), since all global objects I can access, like `process`, are placed on the `global`:

```
global.process === process // true
```

However, when I output `this` it outputs an empty object:

```
console.log(this); // {}
```

So what is `this` and `global` objects?

Comment: Is it truly empty? Look at the non-enumerable properties.

Comment: *Where* did you try to put the `this`?

Comment: `this==global // true`